# Singular Chain of a Hyperplane.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I refer to the definitions of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. Is it possible to model a hyperplane $H$ (or half of it) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a singular chain? And if - how would its boundary look like? How do singularities effect the boundary?

Comment: Are you looking for a map $\sigma : \Delta^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$ whose image is $H$? Or a linear combination of such map, with the union of the images being $H$? Or something similar? ($\Delta^k$ is compact, BTW)

Comment: I am looking a singular $k$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or an element of the free abelian group with basis set of those $k$-simplices so that their image (as maps) is $H$.

Comment: So it's what I said. Then by compactness it's not possible ($\Delta^k$ if compact but $H$ isn't).

Comment: What if one defines a $k$-simplex as map $\sigma : \Delta^k \longrightarrow X$ where $\sigma |_{\mathring{\Delta}^k}$ is continuous?

Comment: You should look up basic compactness theorems in topology, e.g. in Munkres topology book. For example, the continuous image of any compact space is compact. And the union of a finite collection of compact spaces is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, by compactness this is not possible. But there is a setting where it makes sense to take certain infinite formal sums of chains; these represent elements of [Borel-Moore homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Moore_homology) rather than ordinary singular homology.